# how to set timer for calculate execution time

Tags: c#, execution

i like to set timer for calculating execution time in c# for particular process in my execution. how can i do this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) to do what you want.

Answer (score 37):

You don't generally use a timer for this - you use a [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx).

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// Do work
sw.Stop();
TimeSpan elapsedTime = sw.Elapsed;
```

If you're performing benchmarking of something relatively fast, it's worth doing it many, many times so that the time taken is significant (I usually go for 5-30 seconds). That's not always feasible, admittedly - and there are many more subtleties which affect real world performance (such as cache hits/misses) which micro-benchmarking often misses out on.

Basically, be careful - but `Stopwatch` is probably the best starting point in many cases.

Comment: +1 for the Stopwatch.StartNew(). Didn't know about that.

Comment: "You don't generally" vs "You generally don't". Enlighten me: are both correct grammar?

Comment: @Martinho: I *think* both are acceptable. It's possible that one is preferred over the other, although I wouldn't know which :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dba5cb7h(v=VS.90).aspx) and attach an action to the [Elapsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bz73xt3(v=VS.90).aspx) event. For instance you can abort your thread... hmm if you are not affraid of the consequences...
Actually you can do that if you want to set a timeout to your process for instance.

If it's just for monitoring, Stopwatch just fits your needs

Comment: Interesting read on aborting threads: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/22/should-i-specify-a-timeout.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/25/careful-with-that-axe-part-two-what-about-exceptions.aspx